# Performance issue when append option value into dynamic form

Tags: javascript, jquery

**html form**

```
    <select class="form-control select2 firstname v1" id="name1_{{$key}}" name="name[]" style="width: 100%;"></select>  
// this is dyamic form it will have around 100 select box.
```

**script**

```
 <script>
        var data  = {!! json_encode($data['member']) !!}; // from php, total: 89 data
        
        //append option value into selectbox
        var option = '<option value="-1" selected disabled>Please Select Name</option>';
                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    option += '<option value="'+item['id']+'">'+item['name']+'</option>';
                }); 
                
                $('.v1').append(option);
        </script>
```

The above code is created from dynamic form, so it will have 100 selection box. When the page renders I will get the data from the database and append into the 100 select boxes, but here I facing the performance issue, it will take around 3-4 min to append the value. Is there any way to solve the performance issue ya?

Comment: 5/6 minutes seems too long even for javascript.
are you sure that most of the time is not in the request to the database/server?

look at "network panel" in javascript console.

Comment: @Roberto, because when I comment out the append code, it will direct render the pages.

Comment: And you for sure do not call the webservice 89 times? Could you check what $(".v1") returns for your page? It might be 1000 Elements to fill them all with the Options might take some time. But everything above 1s is too long I would say rendering should take milliseconds :/